# TFS label deployment to QA or PROD IIS environments

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build-automation, tfsbuild

I am new TFS deployment. Now I have to create automated deployment by giving the label name and environment and its path.

Build script needs to pickup the label version of code and build the code and push to appropriate given IIS environment path.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that labels are being used rather than branches? If a qa and production branch were used tfs build will auto label all the source included in the build with the current build label?

Comment: I would suggest that you switch to creating a build... Storing it in a drop folder and then deploying that validated output. Building for each push means all of your tests need run again...